# Tearoff is not working with map/fromJson to satisfy unnecessary_lambdas in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

in flutter/dart, i have a solution that works to decode json to an object:

```
final jsonObject = jsonDecode(response);
// ignore: unnecessary_lambdas
return jsonObject.map<User>((u) => User.fromJson(u)).toList();
```

the analyzer suggests:
Closure should be a tearoff.
Try using a tearoff rather than a closure.

but, unfortunately, the following do not work:

```
final jsonObject = jsonDecode(response);
return jsonObject.map<User>(User.fromJson).toList();
```

```
final jsonObject = jsonDecode(response);
return jsonObject.map(User.fromJson).toList();
```

here is the error:

> type '(Map<String, dynamic>) => User' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => dynamic' of 'f'

is the syntax correct?
my other guess is that i am receiving some json that includes more properties than i am attempting to map to an object. but, my fromJson method i think is agnostic to those properties. here is the class:

```
class User {
  final int id;
  final String name;

  const User({required this.id, required this.name});

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return User(
      id: json['id'],
      name: json['name'],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The syntax is correct. Also this has nothing to do with the json having additional properties. See this discussion for more info https://github.com/dart-lang/linter/issues/3226

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be my situation. Are you able to share as an answer for me to mark? It seems the answer is that the analyzer is mistaken on this.

Answer (score 0):

Your json has nothing to do with it. Try disabling an explicit cast.

Add `analysis_options.yaml` to your file:

```
analyzer:
  language:
    strict-casts: false
```

After that, restart Dart Analysis Server (sometimes you may need to restart the IDE). This will prevent an explicit cast and allow the use of tear-off.

Alternatively, you can do the casting a little earlier in the code:

```
final jsonObject = jsonDecode(response) as Map<String, dynamic>;
return jsonObject.map(User.fromJson).toList();
```

---

You can find more details here:

- [Customizing static analysis](https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options)

Answer (score 0):

The tear-off `User.fromJson` is not smart enough to infer the type of the argument.

If you still want to use [unnecessary_lambdas](https://dart.dev/tools/linter-rules/unnecessary_lambdas) and the tear-off, replace

```dart
final jsonObject = jsonDecode(response);
```

with

```dart
final jsonObject = List<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(jsonDecode(response));
```